# Apply command to list of elements separated by \and

Tags: macros, lists, expansion

I am trying to build a command similar to the `\author` command. It takes one argument with is actually a list of arguments separated by `\and`. The command needs to apply another command like `\underline` or `\emph` to each element of the list. My current approach is

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\newcommand{\mylist}[1]{%
    \def\and{\noexpand\endgroup \noexpand\underline\noexpand\begingroup}%
    \edef\myinternallist{\noexpand\underline\noexpand\begingroup #1\noexpand\endgroup}%
    \show\myinternallist%
    \myinternallist%
}
\begin{document}
    \mylist{Element1 \and Element2}
\end{document}
```

and `\show\myinternallist` yields

```
> \myinternallist=macro:
->\underline \begingroup Element1 \endgroup \underline \begingroup Element2\endgroup .
```

which looks ok to my untrained eye. However, the above code does'nt compile and I have no clue why it does'nt. The expected result looks like this:
[image]

Comment: First of all, `\underline\begingroup abc\endgroup` is illegal: you can't use `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` for delimiting the argument to a macro.

Comment: What do I have to use instead? As I said above, I am not that experienced.

Comment: There are various tools in `etoolbox` or `expl3`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You indeed get

```
\underline \begingroup Element1 \endgroup \underline \begingroup Element2\endgroup
```

but unfortunately `\underline\begingroup Element1 \endgroup` is illegal, because `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` can't be used for delimiting a macro argument.

There are various tools for this; I'll show a solution based on `expl3`, the programming layer of the future LaTeX3.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\mylist}{ O{\underline} m }
 {
  % transfer control to an internal function
  \porst_mylist:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__porst_list_items_seq
\seq_new:N \l__porst_list_output_seq

\cs_new_protected:Npn \porst_mylist:nn #1 #2
 {
  % clear the output sequence
  \seq_clear:N \l__porst_list_output_seq
  % split the input at \and
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__porst_list_items_seq { \and } { #2 }
  % append each item to the output sequence
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__porst_list_items_seq
   {
    % #1 is the given argument, ##1 represents the current item
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l__porst_list_output_seq { #1 { ##1 } }
   }
  % output the sequence with something between items
  \seq_use:Nn \l__porst_list_output_seq {,~} % adjust
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\mylist{Element1 \and Element2}

\mylist[\emph]{Element1 \and Element2}

\end{document}
```

The first step is splitting the input at the `\and` tokens; trailing and leading spaces will be removed; the second step is storing the “formatted” items in another sequence, for using this one with some separator between the items.

[image]

Another possible tool is `etoolbox`; but, as you see, it's much more complicated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\DeclareListParser*{\andlist@do}{\and}
\newcommand{\andlist@sep}{, }
\newcommand{\mylist}[2][\underline]{%
  \def\andlist@output{\@gobble}%
  \andlist@do{\andlist@handler{#1}}{#2}%
  \andlist@output
}
\appto\nocorrlist{\andlist@sep}

\newcommand{\andlist@handler}[2]{%
  \appto\andlist@output{\andlist@sep#1{#2\unskip}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\mylist{Element1 \and Element2}

\mylist[\emph]{Element1\and Element2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Would you mind providing a solution with `etoolbox` as well? I already use the `etoolbox` package and I would like to avoid loading an additional package like `xparse`.

Comment: @porst17 I added it.

Comment: You are right. The `expl3` version is much easier to understand. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @porst17 With `etoolbox` it's more difficult to remove unwanted spaces and also to insert something only *between* items.

Answer (score 8):

If you want a solution not requiring a package, use braces `{}`, but you'll need balance them in the definition. To hidden them when expanded just use `\iffalse` .. `\fi`:

```
\def\and{\unskip\iffalse{\fi} \noexpand\underline{\iffalse}\fi}%
\protected@edef\myinternallist{\noexpand\underline{#1}}%
```

`\edef`cannot be used with arbitrary stuff, so I use `\protected@def`, which means you must enclose the whole definition with `\makatletter` .. `\makeatother`. I've also added `\unskip` (to remove the space at the end of each block) and a space.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a common solution without any `expl3`, `etoolbox` etc. The `\and` macro can be defined as required. We need only three lines of macros:

```
\def\mylist#1{\mylistA #1\and\and}
\def\mylistA#1\and{\ifx\and#1\and\else \and{#1}\expandafter\mylistA\fi}
\def\and#1{$\underline{\rm #1}$ }

\mylist{Element1 \and Element2}
```

**Edit:** Egreg's comment here includes question, how to print separator only between items. This is simple. We stay in three lines and without additional packages and without any hassle:

```
\def\mylist#1{\def\mylistS{\def\mylistS{, }}\mylistA #1\and\and}
\def\mylistA#1\and{\ifx\and#1\and\else \and{#1}\expandafter\mylistA\fi}
\def\and#1{\mylistS $\underline{\rm #1}$}

\mylist{Element1 \and Element2}
```

**Edit2:** If somebody needs to print another separator between last two items then he can use following code. Of course, it is slight more complicated:

```
\def\mylist#1{\def\mylistS{}\def\andA##1{\let\andA=\andB}\mylistA #1\and\and}
\def\mylistA#1\and{\ifx\and#1\and \and{}\else \and{#1}\expandafter\mylistA\fi}
\def\and#1{\ifx\mylistS\empty\else\andA{#1}\fi\mylistS \def\mylistS{$\underline{\rm #1}$}}
\def\andB#1{\ifx\and#1\and{ and }\else{, }\fi}
```

The comma is printed between elements but the word " and " is printed between last two elements.

Comment: There is a trailing space, which might be undesirable in some contexts; what if one wants a “comma and space” only between the items and no trailing comma? With `\seq_use:Nn` you get it very easily, without any hassle; with `\seq_use:Nnnn` you can also set a separator for two items only and for more than two items, with special treatment for the last two.

Comment: I don't see any hassle when I am using TeX primitives. IMHO a big hassle is usage of `expl3`.

Comment: It's not a challenge like “do something using as few tokens as possible”. I ***know*** it's possible using primitives; but I also know that I don't want to reinvent the wheel each time I need a basic construct. High level programming languages were born just for this. If you want to program everything in Assembler, you're welcome, but don't dare say that it's simpler than with C.

Comment: Writting four lines of code isn't reinventing the wheel. It is normal praxis of TeX progamming. On the other hand I don't need to know thousands macros and its parameters for various usage. The knowledge of 300 primitives is sufficient.

Comment: It's ***your*** normal praxis. Please, don't insist, unless you prove that Assembler is superior to C.

Comment: The "Assembler to C" is bad comparison. Assemler (and machine code) *is* designed to implement new level (ie. C, for example). But TeX *isn't* designed for this. The bad idea is to forget that there exists TeX. If people know TeX then there would be much less problems at tex.sx.com. I only remind that there is TeX and that the problems here can be solved by TeX only by few lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not bound by the idea to limit items by `\and` you may want to take a look at the packages `commado` or `dowith` that I recently discovered when having a similar problem.

With the former you could try something along the lines

```
    \usepackage{commado}
    % ...
    \newcommand{\myList}[2][\underline]{\doWithCSL{#1}{#2}}
```

and call it like

```
    \myList{Element1, Element2}
```

As this would not produce any space between the elements, the following additions will (almost) reproduce the above examples

```
    \usepackage{commado}
    \usepackage{xspace}
    \newcommand{\myul}[1]{\underline{#1}\xspace}
    \newcommand{\myem}[1]{\emph{#1}\xspace}
    \newcommand{\myList}[2][\myul]{\doWithCSL{#1}{#2}}
    % ...
    \mylist{Element1, Element2}!

    \mylist[\myem]{Element1, Element2}!
```

(the exclamation mark shows that the `\xspace` helps suppressing the trailing space if not needed)

All packages are part of the standard distribution.